# Headings differ in the revisions list from the actual post

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Below is what it looks like on the actual post, which is normal font. This is also how it will render in the post preview.

[image: Normal font]

Below is what it looks like in the revisions list, which is pixelated font. This is also the case for timeline view, but it is identical so one image suffices.

[image: Pixelated font]

I thought the pixel font was kinda neat, but then it turns out to not be how it shows up. In these examples, it is inside of a block quote but the case is also the same if it is not in a blockquote

This happens both on meta and main:

[image]

Comment: Hah, I would never have noticed. I have pixelation all over the darn place :D

Comment: Noticed this as well when looking at your edits.  Curiously, who is it that actually makes the code fixes for these things?  A particular gaming.SE mod, or a general SE developer?  Sorry, relatively new to the SE model, so I'm not sure.

Comment: @kazza It's the SE devs. None of the Gaming mods are on the team. However, they are in charge of highlighting important issues with the team if they find it necessary.

Comment: Likewise, none of the sites have their own devs. The devs work on the network as a whole, although some participate in various sites all across the network, out of both their own interests and routine checkups. I can't definitively say they read all sites equally, but if people feel a particular subject might not be getting enough attention then it often either gets brought up on Meta Stack Overflow (if it's a general network issue) or otherwise highlighted on the corresponding meta site (if it is a problem unique to the specific site, like this one).

Comment: @kazza I'm very glad to hear that. If you have any questions, feel free to ask what you want.

Comment: @Grace I'm looking into this. @Badp I didn't design the Ubuntu site either. @Kazza welcome to SE!